# Trim variable in bash

Tags: regex, string, bash, sed

I need to trim the variable `wordpress.tar.gz` to `wordpress`.

I've tried:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
dir=wordpress.tar.gz
echo $dir
RELEASE=$($dir | sed "s/-.tar.gz//")
echo ${RELEASE}
```

Comment: You have an issue with the regex pattern: dots must be escaped and the dash  should not have been used, I do not see any dash in the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use string expansion:

```
RELEASE="${dir%%.*}"
```

See the [online Bash demo](https://ideone.com/xVS7Fd):

```
dir=wordpress.tar.gz
RELEASE="${dir%%.*}"
echo "$RELEASE"
# => wordpress
```

The `${dir%%.*}` part removes the longest chunk of text from the end (due to `%%`) until the first dot char.

If you want to use `sed`, you may remove all the string starting with (and including) the first dot:

```
RELEASE="$(sed 's/\..*//' <<< $dir)"
```

Here, `\..*` matches a dot and then any zero or more chars to the end of string, and the match is replaced with an empty string (is removed) since the RHS is empty.

Answer (score 1):

```
RELEASE=$(echo $dir | sed "s/\.tar\.gz//")
```

Comment: It does not make sense to fork two sub-shells (one for `$(cmds)`, another for `| cmd`) and spawn `sed` to do exactly what the standard POSIX's built-in variable expansion can do: `RELEASE="${dir%.tar.gz}"`